# Scipy kstest returns different p-values for similar sets of values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, p-value, uniform-distribution

In Python 3.6.5 and scipy 1.1.0, when I run a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to check a uniform distribution, I obtain two opposite results (from a p-value perspective) if I feed the kstest function with a row or column vector:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

>>> np.random.seed(seed=123)
>>> stats.kstest(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(10000, 1)), 'uniform')

KstestResult(statistic=0.9999321616877249, pvalue=0.0)

>>> np.random.seed(seed=123)
>>> stats.kstest(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(1, 10000)), 'uniform')

KstestResult(statistic=0.9999321616877249, pvalue=0.00013567662455016283)
```

**Do you know why this would be the case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mentioned in the [docstring of `kstest`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html) that when the first argument to `kstest` is an array, it is expected to be a *one-dimensional* array.   In your examples, you are passing *two-dimensional* arrays (where one of the dimensions is trivial in each case).  It turns out that the code in `kstest` will not do what you expect when the input array is two-dimensional.

The easy fix is to flatten the array before passing it to `kstest`.  The `ravel()` method can be used to do that.  For example,

```
In [50]: np.random.seed(seed=123)

In [51]: x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(10000, 1))

In [52]: stats.kstest(x.ravel(), 'uniform')
Out[52]: KstestResult(statistic=0.008002577626569918, pvalue=0.5437230826096209)

In [53]: np.random.seed(seed=123)

In [54]: x = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(1, 10000))

In [55]: stats.kstest(x.ravel(), 'uniform')
Out[55]: KstestResult(statistic=0.008002577626569918, pvalue=0.5437230826096209)
```